# Swap areas using python

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm new to blender scripting and I'm trying to make a little addon to swap areas, I know, ctrl+click on the editor's corner make this instead of spliting the editor, but the area is very small and sometimes end clicking anything else specially when using multiple monitors.

I'm new to python but learning, now this is the code that I have:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Simple area swapper",
    "category": "Window"
}

import bpy

class SwapArea(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname   = "area.swaparea"
    bl_label    = "Swap Areas"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        bpy.context.window.cursor_set("HAND")

        if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            print('swaping areas')

            # bpy.ops.screen.area_split(direction='HORIZONTAL')
            bpy.ops.screen.area_swap('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

            bpy.context.window.cursor_set("DEFAULT")
            return{'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type == 'ESC':
            bpy.context.window.cursor_set("DEFAULT")
            return{'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SwapArea)

    wm  = bpy.context.window_manager
    km  = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Screen')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(SwapArea.bl_idname, 'SPACE', 'PRESS', shift=True)

    addon_keymaps.append(km)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SwapArea)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager

    if wm.keyconfigs.addon:
        for km in addon_keymaps:
            for kmi in km.keymap_items:
                km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
                wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.remove(km)

    addon_keymaps.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If I run the code to split the area it runs fine, but when running bpy.ops.screen.area_swap('INVOKE_DEFAULT') nothing happens as far as I see in the API docs, this method doesn't take any param to indicate which areas will swap. I'm getting lost with it, so if someone can give some help.